# How to modify .net Property using Reflexil v1.5?

Tags: .net, properties, .net-assembly, reflexil

I need to modify a .net Assembly that I have lost source for and the only modification I need is to set the property to return 0 instead of 1.

The property is a get only property and there are code inside the get method.
I'm trying to do this using the Reflexil v1.5 plugin inside the Telerik JustDecompile but Reflexil just lets me modify the IL inside the methods and not inside the property get or set blocks.

Does anyone know how to modify the IL inside a Property using Reflexil please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved.
I updated the Telerik JustDecompile to the latest version and now, the get and set blocks inside a Property could be expanded in the list of objects and it will be treated as a code-block, so Reflexil would be able to modify it.